# How to check if phone number already exist?

Tags: magento2, customer, address-attribute

Is there a way to validate a phone number has already been used by customer programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the **Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php** class and then need to override **createAccountWithPasswordHash** method  of the class.

also need to override below file

```
vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml
```

Comment: i just need to check if it already exists or not

Comment: For that you need to code in your custom module after override class and it's method.